# How do I find the path where python3 is installed?

Tags: python

I current trying to use TwilioQuest to learn Python. I have installed Python 3.7 and have followed their instructions but keep getting error messages when I run their code. I am required to find out where Python is installed on my machine but cannot get this information following their recommended steps.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `which python3` if you are on linux ?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  What *are* "their recommended steps", and what is not working about that?

Comment: Linux, MacOS, and Windows all have command-line facilities to locate files by name, as well as commands to give you the path to which a command resolves.  Where are you stuck in finding the file location?

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in `sys` module, you can return a string representing the  absolute path to the interpreter that is running the current script or terminal session with `sys.executable`

Example

```py
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code:

```
find /usr/ -iname python*
```

It will output all the python installations on your pc. If you are looking for a specific version you can replace * with version number.

Comment: That doesn't help locating the python which actually  runs when executing the program. Using `which python` does, as indicated in the first comment

Answer (score -1):

Try navigate to the directory C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python.

I found it in this installation guide ([https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html#:~:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20directory%20C,icon%2Ffile%20python.exe.](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20directory%20C,icon%2Ffile%20python.exe.))

Comment: This is incorrect, python installation directories can vary from install to install. Use a program locator, such as the [which command](https://ss64.com/bash/which.html).